# LINQ Query to obtain only the list names

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, linq

How can I get only the lists present in a particular site?
I've tried the following one:

```
var listNames = from SPList list in web.Lists
                 where list.BaseTemplate !=
                 SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary
                 select list.Title;
```

But it also shows the workflow history,web part gallery etc. which are not required.How can I get rid of this problem?
Waiting eagerly for your answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter out hidden lists:

```
var lists = web.Lists.OfType<SPList>().Where(l => l.Hidden == false && l.BaseTemplate != SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary).ToList();
```